# Why "format as internal storage" is not working when installing new apps?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g

I use my SD card with "format as internal storage".

When I plug my mobile on the PC I see a single huge storage with 10gb free.

But when trying to install a new app, is says that storage is full, and the "settings"->"storage" shows separated internal storage full and SD card with 10gb free.

Why it's not working? Is this a known issue?

I have a Moto G3 with Android 6.0.

[image]

Comment: Tap on SD card from screen on screenshot than tap on 3 dot menu or menu key if you have it and then choose migrate data.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I haver only "rename", "eject" and "Format as portable" options there.

Comment: Well, in that case your  sd card is primary storage, and why you see only one storage when connect to pc - that is normal when you adopt whole sd card. I don't know why but is seems like android is little messed up in your case it should install new apps to SD.  However if you want to be able to install apps than you'll havr to move some apps from internal to adopted storage. Maybe cleaning cache could help you but that is temp fix.

Comment: Can you reformat as internal again ? If need be after making it portable and then internal. Also it appears that it is a 32 Gb card which is fine but if it is 64Gb card then it is a [known problem](https://www.amazon.co.uk/marshmallow-installed-adopting-wondering-handling/forum/Fx3SJZDUX6PHR8A/Tx31KA78FWNMHUY/1/ref=cm_cd_et_voterdr?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B014KT0KWE&cdMSG=addedToThread&cdShowComment=Mx1KLRHIJUQ7IMZ&cdSort=oldest&newContentID=Mx1HPS0GV7OVKWG&newContentNum=1#Mx1KLRHIJUQ7IMZ)

Comment: Eject SD card and if the phone works or if contents of SD readable on a laptop then you can be sure that adoptable-storage didn't work as expected. Hence above recommendation to reformat as portable and then adoptable-storage

Comment: on the next day, the sdcard did stop working, I had to buy a new one, now I'm using as external storage.

Answer (score 2):

All the apps you install go into Internal Storage by default.
You need to move them to your SD Card, even if you formatted it as internal storage.

Go to Settings -> Apps -> (Any Individual app) -> Storage -> Change -> SD Card.

[image: Move to SD Card]
[image: Moving App...]

PS : But you can't do this for most Google Apps and System Apps

Comment: Isn't the "format as internal" suppose to treat the sdcard as internal, and show me a single storage, so I shouldn't care bout sdcard vs internal storage?